# how state parameter prevent CSRF attacks

Tags: oauth

In page at [OAuth 2.0 page](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-request/) says that as below:
state (recommended)  The state parameter is used by the application to store request-specific data and/or prevent CSRF attacks. The authorization server must return the unmodified state value back to the application.

But I'm not clear about how state prevent CSRF attacks. For my idea, If someone catch the pakage, is that sure the request query parameter also been known, So he can send it back again to fade this response.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to store the `state` in the user's session (if it exists) or by setting it in a secure httponly cookie (if the app is stateless). Then in your callback function you compare those (the `state` from the query and the one from session/cookie).

If by saying "package" you mean just HTTP traffic (a man-in-the-middle attack), then if you are using HTTPS protocol - nothing can be hijacked. That's why it's highly recommended to use OAuth only through HTTPS.